# Git - Is it possible to have multiple .gitignores for multiple remotes?

Tags: git, vue.js, github, heroku, gitignore

In my current `Vue` and `express` app, I have to remotes: origin (GitHub) and heroku (herokuapp.com). Heroku is for deployment of my app.

[image: This is my file-structure]

In the `client` folder, I have the Vue source code that shouldn't be deployed to heroku. Anyways, I would like to push that folder to GitHub.

Is it possible that I push the whole source code I wrote to GitHub (excluding the `node_modules` and `.vscode`), but only my `server` folder and `package.json`/`package-lock.json` to heroku?

Comment: Without maintaining separate branches, no.

Comment: How would you do it in seperate branches? That would also be possible for me!

Comment: First you need to determine if it is absolutely necessary. I personally don't see an issue in deploying the client folder. It's just some files and whether the files are executed has to be set in package.json or Procfile. Second if you are working with heroku git Heroku only deploys from the master branch. An exception is if you set up a pipeline via their web page. --- It is possible but I heavily discourage it. As for how look up on how to work with git branches. It's too much to sum up in few words.

Comment: Can I have a .gitignore file for every branch? Also when I merge them?

Comment: You can have a .gitignore file in every branch.  
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b you will have to modify the default merge strategy through .gitattributes.

Comment: Could you give me an example, how that .gitattributes file should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just created another git repository in `client` from which I can now take all the source code. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You could add your critical file to the .gitignore and remove it when not needed with command line &&. Then you can always copy and paste the command you'll have written once.